# Is it possible to change reflection direction?

Tags: lighting, reflection

Completely new Blender user here. I'm part of a work training program and am just beginning to learn how to use Blender. As a personal goal I am trying to cobble together a Companion Cube from Portal and managed to make the core of the thing (I don't know how to be honest, just messing around with buttons) and I added a reflective floor underneath it for a neat look:

[image]

My question is if it's possible to change the direction of the reflection so that only the centermost corners are aligned while the left and right, from camera perspective, are not. Here's a crappy MSPaint mockup to illustrate:

[image]

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help, much appreciated from a complete newbie.

Edit: HenrikD's suggestion is step in the right direction, thanks a lot! [image]

Comment: try moving the plane down or rotating it a little. Light work like it does, you need to use it that way. Its not 2D drawing

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are talking about. Could you edit the question and try to define your desired result in more detail?

Comment: tip: get a real object and a real mirror, put the mirror on a table and move the object around / move your head while looking at the object+mirror+reflection. You'll soon figure out how to position your object and camera on blender (if the image you want is possible in real life).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the normal input to obtain some various deformation effects (distorting mirror) so:

[image]

The node setting is the following (mix rgb is only here for the gif above):

[image]

The mapping: add some X if the view is Y aligned and some Y if the view is X aligned. There is probably some possible calculation to do it automatically from other inputs.

Another distorting mirror, as example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It maybe helps to draw a picture which is more accurate in 3d, so we see what you want exactly.

You could try to move and rotate the reflective plane as @HenrikD suggests, 
you might even use a convexly or concavely bent floor to deform the reflection. 
If you want to make very specific changes to a reflection, you might actually try to have a real object (which you then can modify how you want) as a "fake" reflection and place that under a partially transparent plane.

Comment: Surface normals can be used to change ' the direction ' of the reflection without changing the geometry, but that would not look realistic at all so I doubt that the question is actually about that... I think there could be some sort of misunderstanding in the question here...

Comment: I took the advice HenrikD gave me and made a more accurate render of the desired effect however now I seem to be missing emissions in my render. Were my actions wrong or were my expectations wrong?